# QGIS Problem with extract and warp modules in modeler?

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-modeler, coordinate-system

I have problems using the gdal modules extract and warp in the modeler. They run correctly when started without the modeler, but when I integrate them in the modeler they won't work.
The only input I do set is the raster layer.

The process ends with the known remark:

> "Oooops! The following output layers could not be open
>   Output Layer: C:\Users\sven\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\d2999fed6cd643a280f809eb0bee2373\OUTPUTALG0.tif
>   The above files could not be opened, which probably indicates that they were not correctly produced by the executed algorithm
>   Checking the log information might help you see why those layers were not created as expected"

The Log states everything is OK and ends with:

> "Executed 1 algorithm total.
>   Converting outputs.
>   Loading resulting layers"

(If more information is needed ask for it)

The ogr-protocol states that the "data source is invalid"

As mentioned everything works fine, if I dont use the modeler.

Comment: In the model, have you tried setting the result to save as a file and not as a temporary file?

Comment: Yes, and both produce the same error.